# How to use touches with jquery-mobile in my android webview

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, webview, touch

I have created a jquery mobile site that relys heavily on tap, taphold, and swipe.  When I put it into my webview, those touches aren't working.  I can touch to scroll the window, a single touch hides the footer navbar so I know somewhere in there touches are hitting something.  But my navbar #links don't work, and the taphold and swipe never register.

may MainActivity contains:

```
private WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
            webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        }
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
```

If I view this with just the devices browser everything works fine.  There must be a setting I didn't set since I'm unable to get a touch using any of these that worked in a normal browser window.

```
$( ".wrapper" ).on( "swiperight", swiperightHandler );
$("p").on("taphold",function(event){
Hammer('p').on('hold', function(event) { alert("BOOYA"); }); 
$( "p" ).bind( "click", function() {  alert("something");});
mycontent.addEventListener("load", doSomething, false);
```

and my webpage has

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/jquery.hammer-full.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

these scripts being loaded.

Sample of html content, nothing dynamic:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page20"  data-theme="c">
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="indent1"><span class="g" id="5.1">5.1</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolo
        </p>
        <p class="indent1"><span class="g" id="5.2">5.2</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolo
        </p>
        <p class="indent1"><span class="g" id="5.3">5.3</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolo
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the bottom navbar that has the main links, that isn't linking:

```
<div class="footerimage" data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed"  data-fullscreen="true" data-id="fixedfooter" data-hide-during-focus=""> 
            <div  data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top" > 
            <ul> 
                <li><a href="#INDEX"  data-transition="none"><img  src="css/images/practices_on.png" height="38" width ="28"><br>Practices</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#BOOKMARK" data-transition="none"><img src="css/images/bookmarks_off.png" height="38" width ="28"><BR>Bookmarks</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SITEINDEX" data-transition="none"><img src="css/images/index_off.png" height="38" width ="34"><BR>Index</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SEARCH" data-transition="none"><img src="css/images/search_off.png" height="38" width ="32"><BR>Search</a></li>  
            </ul> 
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your HTML structure. if `p` or `.wrapper` are created dynamically you have to add the listener to the parent element. example `$( "#page1" ).on( "swiperight", ".wrapper", swiperightHandler );`

Comment: Added some more info, I hope it helps.  It's hard to believe jquery-mobile doesn't work